# how can i get product data with different routing pattern in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database, routes, controller

controller function to get products with category:

```php
public function category(Request $request, $slug = null, $slug1 = null, $slug2 = null)
{
    if (Session::has('currency')) {
        $curr = Currency::find(Session::get('currency'));
    } else {
        $curr = Currency::where('is_default', '=', 1)->first();
    }

    $cat = null;
    $subcat = null;
    $childcat = null;
    $minprice = (isset($request->min)) ? $request->min : 0;
    $maxprice = (isset($request->max)) ? $request->max : 0;
    $sort = $request->sort;
    $minprice = round(($minprice / $curr->value), 2);
    $maxprice = round(($maxprice / $curr->value), 2);

    if (!empty($slug)) {
        $cat = Category::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
        $data['cat'] = $cat;
        $prodcs = Product::select(
            "*",
            DB::raw('(CASE WHEN size IS NULL THEN price ELSE size_base_price END) AS price_filter')
        );

        $prodcss = Product::select(
            "*",
            DB::raw('(CASE WHEN size IS NULL THEN price ELSE size_base_price END) AS price_filter')
        );

        $minamount = $prodcs->where('category_id', $cat->id)->orderBy('price_filter', 'ASC')->first()->price_filter;
        $maxamount = $prodcss->where('category_id', $cat->id)->orderBy('price_filter', 'DESC')->first()->price_filter;
        // $maxamount = $maxamount + 1;
    }

    if (!empty($slug1)) {
        $subcat = Subcategory::where('slug', $slug1)->firstOrFail();
        $data['subcat'] = $subcat;

        $minamount = @Product::where('subcategory_id', $subcat->id)->orderBy('price', 'ASC')->first()->price;
        $maxamount = @Product::where('subcategory_id', $subcat->id)->orderBy('price', 'DESC')->first()->price;
    }

    if (!empty($slug2)) {
        $childcat = Childcategory::where('slug', $slug2)->firstOrFail();
        $data['childcat'] = $childcat;

        $minamount = @Product::where('childcategory_id', $childcat->id)->orderBy('price', 'ASC')->first()->price;
        $maxamount = @Product::where('childcategory_id', $childcat->id)->orderBy('price', 'DESC')->first()->price;
    }

    $firstPrice = (isset($request->price[0])) ? $request->price[0] : "";
    $secondPrice =  (isset($request->price[1])) ? explode('-', $request->price[1]) : "";
    $thirdPrice = (isset($request->price[2])) ? explode('-', $request->price[2]) : "";
    $fourthPrice =  (isset($request->price[3])) ? $request->price[3] : "";

    $prods = Product::select(
        "*",
        DB::raw('(CASE WHEN size IS NULL THEN price ELSE size_base_price END) AS price_filter')
    );

    $prods->when($cat, function ($query, $cat) {
        return $query->where('category_id', $cat->id);
    })->when($subcat, function ($query, $subcat) {
        return $query->where('subcategory_id', $subcat->id);
    })->when($childcat, function ($query, $childcat) {
        return $query->where('childcategory_id', $childcat->id);
    });

    if (isset($request->price[0]) || isset($request->price[1]) || isset($request->price[2]) || isset($request->price[3])) {
        $prods->where(function ($query) use ($firstPrice, $secondPrice, $thirdPrice, $fourthPrice) {
            if ($firstPrice != "") {
                $query->having('price_filter', '<', $firstPrice);
            }

            if (!empty($secondPrice)) {
                $query->having('price_filter', [$secondPrice[0], $secondPrice[1]]);
            }

            if (!empty($thirdPrice)) {
                $query->having('price_filter', [$thirdPrice[0], $thirdPrice[1]]);
            }

            if ($fourthPrice != "") {
                $query->having('price_filter', '>', $fourthPrice);
            }
        });
    }

    if (!isset($request->price[0]) && !isset($request->price[1]) && !isset($request->price[2]) && !isset($request->price[3])) {
        $prods->when($minprice, function ($query, $minprice) {
            return $query->having('price_filter', '>=', $minprice);
        });

        $prods->when($maxprice, function ($query, $maxprice) {
            return $query->having('price_filter', '<=', $maxprice);
        });
    }

    $prods->when($sort, function ($query, $sort) {
        if ($sort == 'date_desc') {
            return $query->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
        } elseif ($sort == 'date_asc') {
            return $query->orderBy('id', 'ASC');
        } elseif ($sort == 'price_desc') {
            return $query->orderBy('price_filter', 'DESC');
        } elseif ($sort == 'price_asc') {
            return $query->orderBy('price_filter', 'ASC');
        }
    })->when(empty($sort), function ($query, $sort) {
        return $query->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
    });

    $prods = $prods->where(function ($query) use ($cat, $subcat, $childcat, $request) {
        $flag = 0;

        if (!empty($cat)) {
            foreach ($cat->attributes as $key => $attribute) {
                $inname = $attribute->input_name;
                $chFilters = $request["$inname"];

                if (!empty($chFilters)) {
                    $flag = 1;

                    foreach ($chFilters as $key => $chFilter) {
                        if ($key == 0) {
                            $query->where('attributes', 'like', '%' . '"' . $chFilter . '"' . '%');
                        } else {
                            $query->orWhere('attributes', 'like', '%' . '"' . $chFilter . '"' . '%');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (!empty($subcat)) {
            foreach ($subcat->attributes as $attribute) {
                $inname = $attribute->input_name;
                $chFilters = $request["$inname"];

                if (!empty($chFilters)) {
                    $flag = 1;

                    foreach ($chFilters as $key => $chFilter) {
                        if ($key == 0 && $flag == 0) {
                            $query->where('attributes', 'like', '%' . '"' . $chFilter . '"' . '%');
                        } else {
                            $query->orWhere('attributes', 'like', '%' . '"' . $chFilter . '"' . '%');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (!empty($childcat)) {
            foreach ($childcat->attributes as $attribute) {
                $inname = $attribute->input_name;
                $chFilters = $request["$inname"];

                if (!empty($chFilters)) {
                    $flag = 1;

                    foreach ($chFilters as $key => $chFilter) {
                        if ($key == 0 && $flag == 0) {
                            $query->where('attributes', 'like', '%' . '"' . $chFilter . '"' . '%');
                        } else {
                            $query->orWhere('attributes', 'like', '%' . '"' . $chFilter . '"' . '%');
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $prods = $prods->where('status', 1)->get();
    $prods = (new Collection(Product::filterProducts($prods)))->paginate(24);

    $data['prods'] = $prods;
    $data['minamount'] = $minamount;
    $data['maxamount'] = $maxamount;

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $data['ajax_check'] = 1;
        return view('includes.product.filtered-products', $data);
    }

    return view('front.category', $data);
}
```

web.php file code

```php
// CATEGORY SECTION
Route::get('/{category?}/{subcategory?}/{childcategory?}','Front\CatalogController@category')->name('front.category');
Route::get('/{slug1}/{slug2}','Front\CatalogController@subcategory')->name('front.subcat');
Route::get('/{slug1}/{slug2}/{slug3}','Front\CatalogController@childcategory')->name('front.childcat');
Route::get('/categories/','Front\CatalogController@categories')->name('front.categories');
Route::get('/childcategories/{slug}', 'Front\CatalogController@childcategories')->name('front.childcategories');

// CATEGORY SECTION ENDS
```

Hello im new to Laravel backend, I want to get data on category pages with different url pattern like

```
/{category}
/{subcategory}
/{childcategory}
```

this above code working like

```
/{category}/{subcategory}/{childcategory}
```

I want to shorten the url please the help will be much appreciated

Comment: Please, edit your question and correctly copy-paste the code, it is unreadable and very hard to edit for you

Comment: What happens if two or more subcategories or child categories under different categories happens to have the same name/slug? How would you know which the client expects?

Comment: i can edit the slugs but i want this with shorten urls i dont want subcategory url with category slug it gives the me the output with /category/subcategory but i want directly /subcategory

Comment: Just check each category and subcategory table for the slug. But you're going to want to validate that it's unique on all tables when creating the categories and subcategories, or use unique slugs.

Comment: i can edit them via admin panel but thats not a problem here everyone

Comment: Welcome to SO ... is this a single table of categories, an adjacency list? (there is some parent_id field for each category?)

Comment: the tables are different for categories, subcategories and childcategories